# Batch-associating assets with entries via plugin or MySQL

Tags: mysql, movabletype

I used the Asset Handler plugin -- https://github.com/naoaki011/mt-plugin-assethandler -- to upload a whole bunch of assets to MT at once from a migrated installation where I wasn't using assets. What I'd like to do is find some automatic way to associate each asset with an entry where the filename used for each is mentioned somewhere in the entry itself.

I poked around to see if there was a plugin to do this, but nothing has turned up. Maybe some MySQL code would do it?

Comment: Can you describe more exactly what you mean by "where the filename used for each is mentioned somewhere in the entry itself"? Are these filenames going to appear in `IMG` tags' `src` values? Or the filename will just be mentioned somewhere in the text? Or?

Comment: Mentioning the filename somewhere in the text is all I really need.

Answer (score 0):

Could you also precise what you mean by "associate each asset with an entry"? You want the association to appear in the CMS UI (the entry edit screen listing the asset and the asset edit screen referencing the entry it's "used" on?) or are you aiming at something else?

If what you need is a valid association of objects within MT, then the MT Perl API is a good path. I'd need an example of entry text / asset and your expected result to give you an example.

Comment: "You want the association to appear in the CMS UI (the entry edit screen listing the asset and the asset edit screen referencing the entry it's "used" on?)" -- yes, precisely. Let's say I have an asset with the filename ImageName.jpg, and I also have a post where somewhere in the entry text I say ImageName.jpg (I generally have very unambiguous naming for the files, this is just an example). I'd then like some way of detecting that and automatically associating the asset with the post in question.